# The effectiveness of the hamburger menu in 2016

Tags: website-design, interface-design, user-experience

How effective would other professionals rate a hamburger menu on its own. Is it necessary to have a menu which is 100% visible and doesn't need a click to be shown. I intend on using the answers here to determine my future projects.

Please note I am talking about mobile / tablet sites. I believe menus shouldn't be hidden in desktop sites.

Here is an example of a mockup I made for my site which is in construction.

[image]

Comment: Actually I thought it was called a MenuBurger

Comment: I still use the combination of "Menu" and the icon. In most cases people understand the meaning of the icon, but not in all cases. I believe there are still too many users out there who do not understand its meaning and using it alone can create unnecessary confusion.

Comment: Be careful of hiding too much behind a hamburger. It's a good feature to use but can limit navigation as you are putting all emphasis on the user opening the menu. Where as on a desktop site that has all to see they may click on something that interests them as it is in front of them.

Comment: I see 'efficiency' and 'effectiveness' as two somewhat different things. I suggest changing 'efficient' to 'effective' in your question title.

Comment: I've since changed my menu to the word menu with a top and bottom border. However from these answers the hamburger can be effective depending on how it's used. Changed the title just for you Bart :p

Comment: What are you really asking here??

Comment: I can get over your use of the hamburger menu, but I have to follow a tangent here: How do you "focus on" a bunch of disparate things? And how do you explain to a client the diff between graphic design, UI design, and web design? Or the combining of UI and UX.   is the least of your concerns, IMHO.

Comment: @plainclothes I put graphic design there because some people won't understand some of the other titles but graphic design has a universal understanding. And I'm "focusing" on a variety of areas until I find my niche (if I decide to narrow it down to one) as I am equally adequate in all of these areas.

Comment: @ZachSaucier I'm asking how effective the icon of a hamburger menu is as the solution to a sites menu. I asked this because I read it can decrease conversion rates. I tried to keep the question short and simple.

Comment: @MaxPower it would be a higher quality question if you quoted and linked to what you read.

Comment: If you're looking for people who only understand "graphic design" then you probably aren't looking for UX jobs. If someone is looking for a UX designer and sees your list, they'll pass. How about just being honest and saying "I do a little of everything, including ..."?

Comment: @plainclothes I really appreciate the criticism, I think I will stick with my wording. I do see where you're coming from though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the hambuerger menu is recognizable by the vast majority of users nowadays, *when in the right context*.

In your example, I do not think it is obvious. I usually expect to see the icon for expanding a menu, whether it be a hamburger icon, three vertical dots or a "menu" link on the top right edge of the screen, possibly the left top. But there in the middle it makes me think it's a control to drag/resize the top part. Adding the word "menu" or making it look more clickable would certainly also help.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I will need to develop mine so it's easier to see its purpose. I would mark this correct but my rep is too low :/

Comment: @MaxPower hmm? There's no rep requirement for marking an answer correct.

Comment: you're right guess I went to mark it up.

Answer (score 6):

Nowadays, it is a well established indicator as a button to reveal a menu. There is no reason to worry that people won't understand what it's for based on the icon alone. However where it's situated and whether it's a button are other indicators that could confuse users.

I tend to find it more obvious when situated on the right hand side like spiral has said, and in your design I think it should also be larger based on the sizes of the text that you're using. It's not 100% clear that it's a button to press and could be mistaken for a logo because of where it's situated, if I were you I would consider inverting the colours to make it more clear, or placing a partial border around it.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Inverting the colours may not be a bad idea, I'll have a play around. :)

Answer (score 3):

*Swing by UX.SE for lots of [discussion on this topic](https://ux.stackexchange.com/search?q=hamburger%20menu).*

## Feature discovery is good

The hamburger icon itself isn't the problem, it's people's tendency to scan quickly and rely on the design to expose important things. If you hide content behind a menu button, users will skip over it until they are looking for something that might be hidden in a menu.

#### Put yourself in the user's shoes

Take a look at these two top nav solutions. Which version is going to drive discovery of the four most important things (whatever they may be)? *Forgive the irritating colors ... I was having fun*

#### Hamburger

[image: hamburger]

#### Hamburger with fries

[image: hamburger with fries]

Notice that the 'burger didn't disappear in the expanded version. There's probably still more things in your site structure. Things like "pictures of car bumpers", "8th grade art projects", "my other businesses". Stuff that you don't *need* people to discover when casually browsing or landing in the middle of your site from a search link.

Comment: I see, it's basically creating a happy medium between the fixed nav bar and the hidden hamburger menu based on hierarchy of your information.